# selecting or binding colmns from a list of data frames

Tags: r, dplyr, reduce

I have a list containing 10 data frame like below (with thousands of rows and 5 columns). I want to create a new data frame essentially with "target_id" (col1) which is common in all 10 data frames and other two columns "best_counts" "tpm".
please help.

```
    [[1]]
                target_id length eff_length est_counts         tpm
    1   ENST00000415118.1      8    3.63786   0.000000   0.0000000
    
    [[2]]
                target_id length eff_length est_counts       tpm
    1   ENST00000415118.1      8    3.63786   0.000000  0.000000
    
    [[3]]
                target_id length eff_length est_counts       tpm
    1   ENST00000415118.1      8    3.63786   0.000000  0.000000
```

Thank you,

I want outout something like below - for ex. concatenating est_counts and tpm for dataframe[[1]] and [[2]]

```
                    [[1]]           [[1]]      [[2]]             [[2]]
'target_id'        'est_counts'     'tpm'      'est_counts'      'tpm'
ENST00000415118.1   0.000000        0.0000000  0.000000           0.0000000
```

Comment: I realised I did not explain my question well, sorry. i want to keep my 'target_id' constant and next to it all 10 'est_counts' and 'tpm' in a dataframe.

Comment: Are the `target_id`s in all _thousands of rows_ unique? Are the `target_id`s in _all 10 data frames_ the same?

Comment: 'target_id' rows are unique in a data frame - but the number of rows in a dataframe is not same as of other dataframe. I want this 'target_id' constant and next to this all (10) 'est_counts' 'tpm' with their file name as identifier.so there will be cases where a 'target_id' is not present in a data frame so NA or blank can be placed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a vector of column names that you want to keep, use `lapply` to select the columns and merge the dataset with `Reduce`.

```
keep_cols <- c('target_id', 'est_counts', 'tpm')
result <- Reduce(merge, lapply(list_data, `[`, keep_cols))
```

Comment: thank you, but realised I did not explain my question well, sorry. i want to keep my 'target_id' constant and next to it all 10 'est_counts' and 'tpm' in a dataframe.

Comment: Thank you but it resulted in to one dataframe ('target_id', 'est_counts', 'tpm')

Answer (score 0):

This variant works essentially the same way as Ronak Shah's answer; it just takes care of adding the necessary `merge` arguments to specify *by* which column shall be merged and which name *suffixes* the lined up columns shall get - the original list is `l`:

```
cols = c("target_id", "est_counts", "tpm")
incol = function () paste(".", col<<-col+1, sep="")  # generate columns number
col = 0                                 # don't forget to reset columns number
Reduce(function (x, y) merge(x, y, "target_id", suffixes=c(incol(), incol())), lapply(l, `[`, cols))
```